# docker container : Exited (1) on "bad" command

Tags: ros, docker, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS in a Docker container. I followed this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker).

Now I am going through the [other tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) and working through them inside the container as "root".

The problem : after sourcing ros_entrypoint.sh, in case I type in any "bad" command (e.g. trying to cd into a directory that doesn't exits) the container stops and I am back to my regular bash shell.

The container status shows : Exited (1)

This is how I get back into the container every time :

```
docker container start CONTAINERID 
docker attach zen_aryabhata (I have also tried : docker exec -it zen_aryabhata bash) 
source ./ros_entrypoint.sh
```

Here's the behavior :

```
root@CONTAINERID:/# cd blah
bash: cd: blah: No such file or directory
root@CONTAINERID:/# source ./ros_entrypoint.sh 
root@CONTAINERID:/# cd blah
bash: cd: blah: No such file or directory
dparkar@MYMACHINE:~$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280658/docker-container-:-exited-(1)-on-%22bad%22-command/) by [dparkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29988/dparkar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: `ros_entrypoint.sh` is not a file to source.

---

It's a wrapper shell script that `source`s the correct `setup.bash` for you and then invokes whatever you passed it in that new environment (from [osrf/docker_images/ros/indigo/ubuntu/trusty/ros-core/ros_entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/5399f380af0a7735405a4b6a07c6c40b867563bd/ros/indigo/ubuntu/trusty/ros-core/ros_entrypoint.sh)):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# setup ros environment
source "/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash"
exec "$@"
```

This file is then configured as the `ENTRYPOINT` of your Docker container, and will be run / prefixed *everytime* you spin up a container.

In a way, when you run the following:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ros:indigo rostopic echo /some_topic
```

it does this (inside the container):

```
/entrypoint.sh rostopic echo /some_topic
```

Which then first `source`s `/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` (as this is an Indigo image) and *then* runs `rostopic echo /some_topic` in that same environment.

According to [bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/exec), `exec` replaces the current shell and will terminate if it cannot execute what you ask it to.

If you `source` the file, it could be that you actually end up in the `exec` line, which after asking it to `cd` to a non-existing directory terminates and as the Docker session now has no active programs any more, it also exits, leaving you at the bash prompt of your host's terminal.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
See #q241349 for a related question.

**Comment by [dparkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29988/dparkar/) on 2018-01-26**:
The reason why I was explicitly doing that is because some commands do not work. e.g. "rostopic", "roscd" and "rosls" are not recognized but "rostopic" and "roscore" are recognized.

**Comment by [dparkar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29988/dparkar/) on 2018-01-26**:
Okay, sourcing just the setup.bash seems to solve it: "source "/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash". But I don't get why I have to source it again if ros_entrypoint.sh is internally calling setup.bash anyway.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
I'm not sure why you had to do that. It would seem to be a different question - which should be posted as a new one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Clearly, the official [ros-docker-docs](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Docker) are wrong and are promoting the above technique which leads to mentioned "bug".

@dparkar's answer is based on the contents of `ros_entrypoint.sh`, where he sources manually with

```
source "/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash
```

This is obviously tedious to do each time one logs into the bash of a container. I simplified it with the following script `source_me.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# setup ros environment
source "/opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/setup.bash"
source "/root/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash"
```

where in the last line I also source other relevant projects. I call it with

```
source source_me.sh
```

each time im logging into the bash.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/67790/sebastian1234/) with karma: 11 on 2021-01-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1